# Draw ID's from a data frame based on conditions and probabilities for the conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sample, sampling

I have the following data frame

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
pop <- c(10,10,10,10,1000,1000)
df <- data.frame(pop,ID)
```

Now I would like to draw unique ID's from this data frame with the condition, that the probability, that I draw an ID with a population of larger or equal of 1000 being 0.1 and that the probability for drawing an ID with a population of lower than 1000 being 0.9.

This is the code, that I have come up with:

```
sample(c(df$ID[df$pop>=1000],df$ID[df$pop<1000]),3, prob=c(0.1,0.9))
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

How can I rewrite this problem so it works without assigning a probability to every ID?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to create a probability vector for each ID and pass that to `sample` function. For IDs having pop `>=1000` probability vector should have `0.1` and for IDs having pop `<1000` vector should contain `0.9`.

```
# Create a probability vector for each ID and pass it to sample function. 
sample(df$ID, 3, prob = ifelse(df$pop>=1000, 0.1, 0.9))
#[1] 4 3 2
sample(df$ID, 3, prob = ifelse(df$pop>=1000, 0.1, 0.9))
#[1] 2 1 4
sample(df$ID, 3, prob = ifelse(df$pop>=1000, 0.1, 0.9))
#[1] 3 2 4
```

**Data:**

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
pop <- c(10,10,10,10,1000,1000)
df <- data.frame(pop,ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes sense, however the only problem I have is, that with this approach I could end up with ID's that are not unique. However, I need unique ID's for my following calculations.

Comment: @Mucteam That's true. It will give you Duplicate ID's. You have to add additional logic to pick unique. One option is that you sample for only `1`  at time.

Comment: So I draw one and the put a condition, that if the next drawn number is already drawn, then i should drop it. But this will affect the probabilities for my other numbers to be drawn right?

Comment: @Mucteam You are correct. I have updated my answer to take `prob` argument from the `sample` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one is your solution:

```
# 1. Data set
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  population = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 1000, 1000))

# 2. Set 'probability' by 'population'
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(probability = ifelse((population >= 1000), 0.1, 0.9))
```